# How to print a Sum of int indexes from the void Main() method in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, console, .net-core-3.0

I'm trying to get and print-out a method from static void main on Console. But when I tried to get the method and print it out, I only get the sum of the last index on main, but on the method I can print the values I need. Why it doesn't work if I do it on the main method? This is what I got:

```
static int MixedSum(int[] v, int[] w)
{
  int rx = 0;
  for (int c = 0; c < v.Length; c++)
  {
    for (int d = 0; d < w.Length; d++)
    {
      rx = v[c] + w[d];
      //Console.WriteLine(rx); //Right values gets print out from here.                  
     }
   }
  return 0;
}
```

And, this is the main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  int[] v = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
  int[] w = new int[] { 4, 5, 6 };

  MixedSum(v, w); //I would like to print it out here.
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: 5 6 7 6 7 8 7 8 9

Comment: Your expected output is an array, but you are trying to store them as an int value. I would store them in another array and return this array at the end.

Comment: Yeah it prints out the sum of each index as an (int) 00 01 02 10 11 12 20 21 22. Vertically. The method requires to return an int for each index sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a delegate:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] v = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] w = new int[] { 4, 5, 6 };

        Action<int> printInt = i => Console.WriteLine(i);
        MixedSum(v, w, printInt);
    }

    static int MixedSum(int[] v, int[] w, Action<int> printDelegate)
    {
      int rx = 0;
      for (int c = 0; c < v.Length; c++)
      {
        for (int d = 0; d < w.Length; d++)
        {
          rx = v[c] + w[d];
          printDelegate(rx);
         }
       }
      return 0;
    }   
}
```

Comment: I have to change the method signature but it works.Thanks! what's the `Action Delegate`, does it work as a collection?

Comment: Delegate is just a pointer to a function that you can pass as argument to another function. `Action Delegate` is a kind of delegate that doesn't return a value (as opposed to `Func` delegates).

Answer (score 1):

You need return int collection instead of one int and pass the result in loop.

```
    static List<int> MixedSum(int[] v, int[] w)
    {
        var rx = new List<int>();
        for (int c = 0; c < v.Length; c++)
        {
            for (int d = 0; d < w.Length; d++)
            {
                rx.Add(v[c] + w[d]);
            }
        }

        return rx;
    }

    // output
    foreach(var num in MixedSum([], [])) {
        Console.WriteLine(num);
    }
```

Comment: @Jacman my mistake try this new update. You need also return rx value.

Comment: I tried this before too, and the compiler says: `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type int because int does not contain a public instance definition GetEnumerator`

Comment: Hm so return List and not convert it to an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print multiple value, you can use IEnumerable and foreach loop. Here is an example:

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    int[] v = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    int[] w = new int[] { 4, 5, 6 };

    foreach( var value in MixedSum( v, w ) )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( value );
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<int> MixedSum( int[] v, int[] w )
{
    for ( int c = 0; c < v.Length; c++ )
    {
        for ( int d = 0; d < w.Length; d++ )
        {
            yield return  v[c] + w[d];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It cannot write the correct value in the Main method, in my opinion, the Console method output the value depends on its execution scope, it only outputs the values in the method. 
In case, there are 2 ways to accomplish the goal.

1. using yield keywords in the IEnumerable list. refer to this [demo code](https://try.dot.net/), just click run to see the result.
2. define the result list in the MixedSum method, then Console.Write the values in the Main method.